# Stripe integration React Issue | secret_key_required | An error occurred in initiatePayment when creating a Stripe customer:\r\nundefined\r\n

Tags: reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments

I  try integrate Stripe Payment with my app React / Next.js

When I list payments and try select payment by card then I get:

```
http://localhost:9000/store/carts/cart_01HEREDSXETVVFCMGGT2W5T2KJ/payment-session
Metoda Żądania:
POST
Kod Stanu:
400 Bad Request
```

I checked error code:

```
code
: 
"secret_key_required"
message
: 
"An error occurred in initiatePayment when creating a Stripe customer:\r\nundefined\r\n"
type
: 
"invalid_data"
```

Currently fallowing to documentation I use only public key.

Q: Can anyone guide me whether this error may come from not passing the Secret Key for the POST request API. or Does this apply to the secret key for payment initialization when creating a Customer?

@update:

```
import {
  CardCvcElement,
  CardExpiryElement,
  CardNumberElement,
} from "@stripe/react-stripe-js"
import {
  StripeCardCvcElementOptions,
  StripeCardExpiryElementOptions,
  StripeCardNumberElementOptions,
} from "@stripe/stripe-js"
import React, { useMemo } from "react"

const PaymentStripe: React.FC = () => {
  const useOptions:
    | StripeCardNumberElementOptions
    | StripeCardExpiryElementOptions
    | StripeCardCvcElementOptions = useMemo(() => {
    return {
      style: {
        base: {
          fontFamily: "Inter, sans-serif",
          color: "#424270",
          padding: "10px 12px",
          "::placeholder": {
            color: "#CFD7E0",
          },
        },
      },
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="flex flex-col relative w-full pb-6">
        <CardNumber options={useOptions as StripeCardNumberElementOptions} />
        <div className="flex items-center mt-12 relative gap-x-4">
          <CardExpiry options={useOptions as StripeCardExpiryElementOptions} />
          <CardCVC options={useOptions as StripeCardCvcElementOptions} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

const CardNumber = ({
  options,
}: {
  options: StripeCardNumberElementOptions
}) => {
  return (
    <div className="border-b border-gray-200 py-2 relative">
      <span className="absolute -top-6 text-gray-700 text-base-regular">
        Card number
      </span>
      <CardNumberElement options={options} />
    </div>
  )
}

const CardExpiry = ({
  options,
}: {
  options: StripeCardExpiryElementOptions
}) => {
  return (
    <div className="border-b border-gray-200 w-full py-2 relative">
      <span className="absolute -top-6 text-gray-700 text-base-regular">
        Expiration date
      </span>
      <CardExpiryElement options={options} />
    </div>
  )
}

const CardCVC = ({ options }: { options: StripeCardCvcElementOptions }) => {
  return (
    <div className="border-b border-gray-200 w-full py-2 relative">
      <span className="absolute -top-6 text-gray-700 text-base-regular">
        CVC
      </span>
      <CardCvcElement options={{ ...options, placeholder: "123" }} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default PaymentStripe
```

Comment: would you mind sharing your code?

Comment: @Tarzan can you check my update.

Comment: would you mind sharing the code for submission please?